# CPU & Memory Usage Log & Performance

Tags: networking, central-processing-unit, network-monitoring, memory-usage, cpu-usage

I want to have an idea of the amount of CPU and memory that is being used. I have a website hosted using IIS, and have clients connecting to it. I want to find out the amount of load that the CPU, RAM and the network has when multiple clients connect. I tried out using tools like Fiddler, the inbuilt Resource Manager, and also some other applications I found on the internet. I just want to keep track of all these data in a file, so I can plot out a graph and find out how the CPU, etc. is performing. I read a few other posts, but didn't find anything that solves the problem. Is there good CPU / Memory Logging tool available, just to plot a graph of the usage, etc.?

EDIT : I want to know of some tool that can save the performance details in a log file, so that I can use it to plot a graph, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention IIS so I'll guess you're using Windows of some sort.  You can use PerfMon in most recent versions of Windows to record performance counters to a log file.  It comes with Windows so there won't be anything else to install.

[Details here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749249.aspx) and [more here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771692%28WS.10%29.aspx).

Comment: perfmon gives only the CPU usage details right? What about the network and memory part of it? Any ideas for those?

Comment: PerfMon has counters for the entire range of performance statistics, that includes memory and network.